# OpenCV cv2 not working in Windows 7

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have a Windows 7 SP1 64 Bit machine with open cv2.4.9 installed and python 2.7.6 installed. 
I use pre compiled version of opencv

The following code works perfectly for me

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import time

cv.NamedWindow("camera", 0)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Now when I try to use this code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, img = cam.read()

winName = "Movement Indicator"
cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while s:
  cv2.imshow( winName,img )

  s, img = cam.read()

  key = cv2.waitKey(10)
  if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyWindow(winName)
    break

print "Goodbye"
```

The window is opened , the camera is initialized (as camera lights are on) , but nothing is displayed and the window closes and the program exits.

WHERE am I going wrong??

QUESTION 2
Can any one also suggest me how to capture live video stream from my Linux machine 192.168.1.3 . The stream is being generated by ffmpeg.

The video stream can be opened in web browser. But I want to capture it with opencv and python.

Comment: Both of your code snippets are working for me using OpenCV 2.4.9 on OS X...

Comment: @MattDMo then where is the problem in my system? Can you give any idea?

Comment: cv2.imshow("camera", img)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow